# Watch Mac's iSight (webcam) on another Mac over LAN

Tags: macbook-pro, video, streaming, webcam

I have two Macs (A MacBook Air, and a MacBook Pro).

Now, I'd like to view the live picture of the webcam of one MacBook on the other. (So, I'd like to ***stream my webcam*** or, equivalently ***use my iSight as an IP Cam***).

A nasty restriction is: I do have a router (and hence a LAN), but it's not connected to the Internet. 3G (cellular network) too is practically non-existent.

I have tried:

- VLC Player: The tutorials on the net are mostly outdated (pre 2012). I tried, but I could not receive the stream. VLC would keep on telling me that it could not open it.
- FFMPEG: It could find the cam and presumably stream it using RTP, but I could not find a way to watch the stream on the other Mac. (Neither with QuickTime, nor with VLC)
- [AtHome Video Streamer](https://itunes.apple.com/app/athome-video-streamer-video/id579486923): This app only sends the image, but there is no app to watch it on the Mac. This app is only available on hendheld devices.

I am not afraid of the command line interface and also prepared to pay a couple of Euro's (Dollars, for that matter) for an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [IP Cam](https://itunes.apple.com/app/ip-cam/id547197538) by Senstic available on the Mac App Store (no affiliation with the developer).

This app claims to work over a private network without needing active connection to the Internet. From the app description:

> INSTRUCTIONS:
>
> 1. Start IP Cam on your mac.
> 2. Take a note on the HTTP access address shown by IP Cam.
> 3. For Wi-Fi remote viewing, enter the same HTTP address into the web browser from another computer or iOS device on the same Wi-Fi network.

Comment: That did indeed work. There where many such apps in the App Store. I did not dare to pick any of them. Thanks to your advice, I now have one that fits my needs.