# Is there a way to stream from iSight camera over RTSP?

Tags: video, streaming, webcam

I'm contemplating using [ZoneMinder](https://zoneminder.com/) to monitor my home. As a first step to see if it works, I'd like to connect it to my MacBook built-in camera over the local network (ZoneMinder itself runs on a Linux server).

So far I failed to find software which would allow me to do that. Is anyone aware of something like this?

This is just to test that I understand how to configure and use ZoneMinder before I invest in a hardware IP camera.

Things I looked at:

1. [Reddit thread about the subject](https://www.reddit.com/r/homebridge/comments/cpdvtq/trying_to_set_up_macbook_camera_as_an_ip_camera/)
2. Apple App Store
3. [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/)
4. https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server an RTSP server which streams static files (?)
5. Searched in Google and Ask Different for combinations of "RTSP", "MacOS", "iSight", "Camera"
6. Searched [ZoneMinder Wiki](https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Welcome) and [Forums](https://forums.zoneminder.com/)

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341079/watch-macs-isight-webcam-on-another-mac-over-lan?rq=1 help?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. At first, it looked promising but it uses its own protocol so doesn't help me in using the camera as a stand-in for a real IP camera that I can configure with ZoneMinder.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/homebridge/comments/cpdvtq/trying_to_set_up_macbook_camera_as_an_ip_camera/, so ffmpeg, VLC or Homebridge seem to be options for others.

Comment: Thanks. I found this reddit thread before asking here but it seems to be involved in setting up an entire HomeBridge server. I'll see if I can just follow the part about ffmpeg.

Comment: Please list the things you already looked at directly in the question.